# How can I duplicate a GameObject with the correct number of copies?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FormationsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject squadMemeberPrefab;
    public int numberOfSquadMembers = 20;
    public int numberOfSquads = 1; 
    public int columns = 4;
    public int gaps = 10;
    public Formations formations;

    private int numofmembers;
    private int numofsquads;
    private GameObject squadToClone;
    private List<GameObject> SquadMembers = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        squadToClone = GameObject.Find("Squad");
        numofmembers = numberOfSquadMembers;
        numofsquads = numberOfSquads;
        formations.Init(numberOfSquadMembers, columns, gaps);
        GenerateSquad();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (numofmembers != numberOfSquadMembers)
        {
            numofmembers = numberOfSquadMembers;
            formations.Init(numberOfSquadMembers, columns, gaps);
            GenerateSquad();
        }

        if (numofsquads != numberOfSquads)
        {
            numofsquads = numberOfSquads;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquads; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(squadToClone);
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateSquad()
    {
        GameObject go = squadMemeberPrefab;
        List<GameObject> newSquadMembers = new List<GameObject>();

        int i = 0;
        for (; i < formations.newpositions.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < SquadMembers.Count)
                go = SquadMembers[i];
            else
                go = Instantiate(squadMemeberPrefab);
            go.transform.position = formations.newpositions[i];
            go.tag = "Squad Member";
            go.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
            newSquadMembers.Add(go);
        }

        for (; i < SquadMembers.Count; i++)
            Destroy(SquadMembers[i]);

        SquadMembers = newSquadMembers;
    }
}
```

In the Update I duplicate the squad:

```
if (numofsquads != numberOfSquads)
            {
                numofsquads = numberOfSquads;
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquads; i++)
                {
                    Instantiate(squadToClone);
                }
            }
```

The problem is that if for example when running the game there is 1 squad and then I'm changing the value of numberOfSquads to 3 then instead duplicating more 2 squads it will duplicate more 3. And then if I will change the value of numberOfSquads from 3 to 4 it will add more 4 squads instead only 1.

And I also want to make that if I change the value of numberOfSquads to be lower then destroy the last squad/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you create a new squad for every numOfSquads. So if you want a total of 3 then you instantiate an extra 3.

Instead set the loop to start at 1(or current squad count) instead of 0 so it skips the amount you already have.

```
if (numofsquads != numberOfSquads)
        {

            for (int i = numofsquads; i < numberOfSquads; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(squadToClone);
            }
            numofsquads = numberOfSquads;
        }
```

Comment: Am I missing something or should this be `i = numofsquads`, and then set `numofsquads = numberOfSquads` at the end? Like this, it would instantiate one less gameobject than in the question, but have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, i should equal the number of squads you already have. This means if you have 3 squads and want 6 the loop will loop from 3 to 5. In the first iteration i will be 3 and create a squad, the next iteration will be 4 and the final iteration will be 5. Giving you 3 extra squads to make the 6.